# Why does J. J. Abrams like to insert the number 47 into his movies?

Tags: jj-abrams

In another question that used to be on this site, I noticed that J. J. Abrams inserts the number 47 into several of his movies. I'm curious about it... Why is the number 47 significant?

Comment: Probably a question only he can answer, unless he's been quoted about it.

Comment: One peculiar item about this is the lost numbers did not include a 47.  I wonder if he'll explain it in about 2 years when he turns 47 :)

Comment: As Bill the Lizard explains in his answer to the question you cite, 47 was an established Star Trek tradition, brought by a graduate of Ponoma College, where 47 was a local tradition. The [Wikipedia article for 47](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/47_%28number%29#As_an_in-joke) has the story as well.

Comment: @gilles you chould add that as an answer

Comment: I've been tuned into 47 since 1971.....I have seen it used is many films dealing with science and military and just about any genre...It even appears in "My Fair Lady". I feel it is a kind of code of the Universe that attracts certain people and even "we" who are attracted to 47, still question its influence and from where? (Maybe Orion.... (just a thought). I know that I have been aware of it constantly and 47 appears continuously in my journey on this planet. It is mystical in its nature... We'll see....

Comment: One of the answers mentions one of the Star Trek writers does this as well. The cartoon Doug does this too, prominently inserting the number 47 everywhere for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 24):

A writer from Star Trek The Next Generation, [Joe Menosky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Menosky) attempted to put the number 47 in all of scripts he worked on. Joe attended [Pomona college](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomona_College#47) where the [47 club](http://www.47.net/47society/) originated. More about the mystery of 47 [here](http://www.pomona.edu/about/pomoniana/the-mystery-of-47.aspx). [JJ Abrams has used 47 throughout his productions](http://www.observersarehere.com/number-47/2009/04/).

In Abrams trademarks [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0009190/bio) lists 'Often makes references to elements of the original "Star Trek" (1966) series'. Although 47 was not in the original Star Trek series it made many appearances in the series to follow. So it can be deduced that Abrams is paying homage to Star Trek tradition by including the number 47 in so many of his productions.

Another thing of note is that in the original Star Trek series: [Production #47](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsession_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)), is titled 'Obsession'.